# JavaScript Date.toLocaleDateString() - set only options

Tags: javascript, date, locale

**Situation:** I want to use the JavaScript function `Date.toLocaleDateString()` to display a date in the users preferred locale. So far so well, but I want to display month and day with the `2-digit` option.

As far as I know, you have to use `Date.toLocaleDateString(locale, options)` to display with options, but which value should I use for the `locale` option? Which variable does the `toLocaleDateString()` read internally to set the locale, so that I can read it out and pass it to the function call with 2 parameters?

Comment: You could try with `undefined`

Comment: From [the MDN page referenced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation) as containing the information on the `locale` parameter: _"If the locales argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used."_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the specification of `toLocaleDateString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/#sec-13.3.2):

> 3. If locales is not provided, then let locales be undefined.

Implying you can set it to `undefined` yourself with no ill effects.  This is backed up by the [MDN reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation):

> If the locales argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used.

So you can call it with:

```
Date.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
```

to get the default locale as if you'd called it with no arguments.

Comment: Thank you, I simply didn't see the remark about undefined.

Comment: @MilConDoin That info itself isn't on the [MDN page for `toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), but the page I linked to is linked behind the "Intl page" text under the "locales" parameter section.